# windows 10 ver1709 is not recognizing my intel hd display driver

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, intel-graphics, windows-10-v1709

Windows 10 ver1709 is not recognizing my Intel HD graphics 530 display driver. It says windows will use basic graphic driver instead. I tried Intel driver updater and there is no update available. there's no update for windows either!

Comment: have you tried the driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the last driver [version 15.60.0.4849](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/27266/Graphics-Intel-Graphics-Driver-for-Windows-15-60-?product=88345) from 11/7/2017. This driver should work with 1709.

If setup.exe fails, [use device manager to manually update the driver](https://support.getmyo.com/hc/en-us/articles/203077175-Windows-is-unable-to-find-a-compatible-driver-for-the-Myo-armband). Here select `Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer`,

[image]

now select `have disk` and point to the folder where you extracted the zip.

Comment: I can't install this driver it says something like you can't install a generic driver because you installed a driver from computer manufacturer. If you want to install the generic driver first you have to uninstall the manufacturer's driver.
I did that but I couldn't install the driver anyway.

Comment: @HosseinMf extract the driver and install the driver via device manager (select update the driver of the basic generic adapter and select the folder with the extracted inf files)

Comment: Not possible. It says the best graphic driver already installed.

Comment: @HosseinMf don't let windows auto select the driver, select **Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer**, now seelct "have disk" and select ere the extracted folder: https://support.getmyo.com/hc/en-us/articles/203077175-Windows-is-unable-to-find-a-compatible-driver-for-the-Myo-armband

Comment: @HosseinMf have you tried the **Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer** option?

Comment: nice to hear this.